# how to add query between params router in nuxtjs

Tags: parameters, routes, nuxt.js, vue-router, nuxtjs3

I want to customize my route in **Nuxtjs** as

```
/slug1?category=cat1/slug2/slug3
```

> the problem in query

Comment: Not sure if it's standard. Still, what did you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

After ? everything will be considered as query.
Instead what you can do is add category as [dynamic route](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/file-system-routing#dynamic-routes)

```
pages/
--| slug1/
-----| _category/
---------| slug2/
------------| slug3
```